# How to fetch azure blob metrics (Classic) using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

i need to fetch azure blob metrics(classic) using powershell. Is there any way to fetch using powershell. I am able to fetch new metrics but not able to fetch azure blob classic metrics

Metrics like 
AnonymousAuthorizationError
AnonymousClientOtherError
AnonymousClientTimeoutError
AnonymousNetworkError
PercentSuccess
PercentThrottlingError
PercentTimeoutError

Answer (score 0):

It is not support currently.

To get all valid metrics, use `Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId "<BLOB SERVICE RESOURCE ID>"`.

If use `Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId "<BLOB SERVICE RESOURCE ID>" -MetricName "AnonymousAuthorizationError" -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -Debug`, you can also find the valid metrics:

[image]

Comment: is there any way other then this to fetch blob classis metrics . like any REST API, or any other client sdk (python , .net etc)

Comment: @VibhuBaliyan Not sure, REST APIs are all [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/), may be you could ask for the other ways in another post, it will be clear.